# java applet cookies

Tags: java, cookies, applet

It seems in at least Firefox 3.6.13 you have to have third-party cookies enabled in order to receive cookies in a java applet.

I see no explicit mention of this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/plugin-dev-guide-1-159174.pdf .

Is this a firefox thing, a new thing, a general thing, or is this a side effect of the code I am maintaining for someone else :-)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone face this issue again... This is a known (and pitifully, still open) bug in Firefox.

See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=441166

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the cookies thing, though it seems logical that Java applets should use the cookie behavior defined in the browser.

OTOH it might be possible to provide this functionality using the JNLP API PersistenceService.  The end user will need Java 1.6.0_10+ for an embedded applet to access the PS.  Here is a [demo. of the PersistenceService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).